# Claudia Api Builder is creating the lambda function but not adding a trigger

Tags: node.js, lambda, aws-lambda, claudiajs, claudia.js

I am using Claduiajs to create lambda functions and i'm still discovering what it can and can't do, so far I was able to create a lambda function that connects to AWS DynamoDB and everything is working as expected, but when I try adding in an API by using Claudia API Builder by following [this tutorial](https://vimeo.com/156232471) the trigger doesn't get added to the lambda function.

The steps I took after setting npm and installing the dependencies were:

Step 1: Write this function up in `main.js`:

```
    const AWS = require('aws-sdk'); // Used for DynamoDB
    const performance = require('performance-now'); // Used to measure performance
    const deepExtend = require('deep-extend'); // Used to deep extend json arrays

    const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region: 'ap-southeast-2'});
    const TableName = 'Agent-commands';

    var ApiBuilder = require('claudia-api-builder'),
    api = new ApiBuilder();

    module.exports = api;

    api.post('/',function(request){
      console.info('request',request);
    });
```

Step 2: Run this command to create the function & api `claudia create --name add-command-for-agent --region ap-southeast-2 --api-module main --timeout 10 --policies policies/*.json`
Once I do that I get this in the terminal:

```
saving configuration
{
  "lambda": {
    "role": "add-command-for-agent-executor",
    "name": "add-command-for-agent",
    "region": "ap-southeast-2"
  },
  "api": {
    "id": "l223cd1rl7",
    "module": "main",
    "url": "https://l223cd1rl7.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/latest"
  }
}
```

When I go to that url I get `{"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}`

When I check my `claduia.json` file that's created by the create command i don't see the url in there, just the id and module.

When I check the lambda function on the AWS console there are no triggers attached.

Am I doing something wrong or is that a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had this issues before and in my case the IAM role did not have the necessary permissions. I'd recheck your IAM role to make sure it has all of the permissions it needs.